# zip function and list comprehension

Tags: python

The following code snippet takes two numbers from the user. Each number is made from digits 0 or 1. The program should write a new number corresponding to the given pair of numbers. The rule is simple: The i-th digit of the answer is 1 if and only if the i-th digit of the two given numbers differ. In the other case the i-th digit of the answer is 0.

This was my approach to solving the problem which gives me the desired output:

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
s = ''
 
for i in range(len(s1)):
    if s1[i] != s2[i]:
        s += '1'
    else:
        s += '0'
        
print(s)
```

This one-line approach is producing the same output, and I am just curious to know how it is doing so but couldn't figure it out. So here I am on Stackoverflow.

```
i=input;print(''.join('01'[a!=b]for a,b in zip(i(),i())))
```

Comment: This is simply an XOR of two binary strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained step by step:

`i=input` - storing the function in `i` to be called later

`zip(i(),i())` - if the user entered `1010` and `1101`, this would return `[(1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]` - the elements of both strings paired up

`for a,b in` - `a` and `b` are the pair from the `zip` (in the example they are first set to a=1 and b=1, then a=0 and b=1, etc.)

`'01'[a!=b]` - `a!=b` will return a boolean - either True or False. `True` = 1 and `False` = 0 so you can use this for indexing. Basically this says `if a!=b: '1'`, `if a==b: '0'`

`''.join` - finally, join all the '0's and '1's together to make one string and print

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make it a oneliner, remove the semicolon and do it like this:

```
print(''.join('01'[a!=b] for a, b in zip(input(), input())))
```

1. Python will ask the user for two input strings
2. `zip` creates an iterable with tuples, so "hi" and "ho" will become [(h,h), (i,o)]
3. in the list comprehension, you've got a string '01' that can be indexed with either 0 or 1
4. that is what your expression `[a!=b]` does, it evaluates to either `True` (1) or `False` (0)
5. because you loop over all tuples, this happens for every character in your input strings
6. finally, `''.join` concatenates all elements in your list, and this gets printed